# Rewrite rules Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem with the `Rewrite Url Wordpress`, I added this code in `functions.php` on my child theme, and I have `already 404 error`.

```
 function custom_rewrite_basic() {
     add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?p=$matches[1]', 'top');
 }
 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Whatever the rule, it does not work

An idea?

thank you

Comment: You just copy and paste the code from https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule.

Please explain what is your goal.

Comment: flush permalink...

Comment: `IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.`

Comment: Ok thanks, I did not know about flush

Comment: I want to do something like that :  `add_rewrite_rule('^outils/produits-ciqual/calories/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?p=390&id=$matches[2]', 'top');`